# does WEB_CONCURRENCY only apply to Worker Dynos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, concurrency, puma

On Rails 4 using Heroku and Puma webserver

I am trying to understand WEB_CONCURRENCY in relation to my dyno.

Currently, I am running on one standard 2x dyno. I am not using any worker dynos, as nothing I am doing needs to processed in the background. According to Heroku's docs the default concurrency is 4: `2X dynos: WEB_CONCURRENCY=4`

**My question is** does concurrency strictly have to do with worker dynos? Since I am not using any worker dynos, should I set WEB_CONCURRENCY to zero?

If there is any documentation that can answer my question in a simple way, please link it over. I am having an overly hard time understanding concurrency and what to set it to based on the dyno I am using.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Puma forks multiple OS processes within each dyno to allow a Rails app to support multiple concurrent requests. In Puma terminology these are referred to as worker processes (not to be confused with Heroku worker processes which run in their own dynos). Worker processes are isolated from one another at the OS level, therefore not needing to be thread safe.

read this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server